# Guaranteed FIFO using JPA (Hibernate implementation) with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I need to persist a queue of tasks in MySQL. When reading them from DB I have to make sure the order is exactly the same as they have been persisted.
In general I prefer to have the solution DB agnostic (i.e. pure JPA) but adding some flavor of Hibernate and/or MySQL is acceptable as well.

My (probably naive) first version looks like:

```
em.createNamedQuery("MyQuery", MyTask.class).setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(count).getResultList();
```

Where `MyQuery` doesn't have any "order by" clause i.e. it looks like:

```
SELECT t FROM MyTasks
```

Would such approach guarantee that the incoming results/entities are ordered in the way they have been persisted? What if I enable caching as well?

I was also thinking of adding an extra field to the task entity which is a timestamp in milliseconds `(UTC from 1970-01-01)` and then order by it in the query but then I might be in a situation where two tasks get generated immediately one after the other and they have the same timestamp.

Any solutions/ideas are welcome!

EDIT:
I just realised that auto increment (at least in MySQL) would throw an exception once it reaches its max value and no more inserts would be possible. This means I shouldn't worry about having the counter reset by the DB and I could explicitly order by an "auto increment" column in my query. Of course I would have another problem to deal with i.e. what to do in case the volume is so high that the largest possible unsigned integer type in MySQL is not big enough but this problem is not nesessarily coupled with the problem I am dealing right now.

Comment: What caching you talk about?

Comment: Second level JPA cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing in a pure JPA solution, cause the entity MyTasks [must have a primary key](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html) I suggest you to use Sequence Generator for its primary key and sort the result of your query using order by clause on the key.

For example:

```
@Entity
class MyTask {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;
```

You can also tight it a little bit with your database using @SequenceGenerator to specify a generator defined in the database.

Edit: Did you take a look at the @PrePersist option for setting the timestamp? Maybe you can combine the timestamp field and the id sequenced generation and order by in this order, so timestamp conflicts are resolved by id comparation (which are unique).

Comment: Yes, I think this is valid suggestion. I will just make sure I use the largest possible unsigned integer in MySQL for the primary key column

Answer (score 0):

Most RDBMS's will store in the order of insertion and given no other instruction will order results that way too. If you don't want to leave it to chance, you have a couple of options.

1) You can generate a reasonably unique ID by using a timestamp and a incrementing fixed-length number,

OR

2) You can just define your table with an autonumbered primary key (which is probably easier).

If the table has a primary key to order by, then by default, most RDBMS's will return things in ascending primary key order... or you can enforce it explicitly in your query.

Comment: It is not true "If the table has a primary key to order by, then by default, most RDBMS's will return things in ascending primary key order". When RDBMS perform full table scan (for example execute SELECT t FROM MyTasks query) it is not necessary to use any index information.

Comment: Option 1) will not guarantee the FIFO behaviour. For example two consecutive tasks could share the same timestamp but the second one could have smaller random number thus come first.

Comment: Option 2) could work provided I explicitly order by this column. The thing is that this table will be heavily used and if some day in the future the counter reaches its max value it will be reset and I guess FIFO might be broken.

Comment: Remember, the IDs are unsigned values. If you're worried about the 4-billion limit of integer, just use a bigint for the id. If your table exceeds 18 quintillion rows, you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

JPA (with or without cache) and RDBMS not guarantee of persisting or uploading sequence when you do not use `order` instruction. To solve task you should add integral primary key to the entity and use it when gather data as it mentioned other answereres.